Standard UI for OAuth2/OpenID login in SPA
I'm planning to implement a user authentication based in OpenID (OIDC) for my single page application built in react.
Which is the standard or recommended way to handle the user authentication flow from the user interface? As far as I can see there are two main approaches to display the authentication provider screen:

Directly redirect to the authentication provider
Use a popup to avoid the redirection in the main window

Is there any other alternative? Does anyone know what is the most common approach to use in a single page application?
Right now I'm considering the approach #2 (using a popup), to avoid losing some context I have in my application that may be lost after coming back from the redirect. But I don't know if this approach can be problematic when using the application with a mobile phone for example.
Any suggestion or recommendation are very welcome.
